# Self join table to compare values

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to compare values in a column to using a join in the same table.
Here is an example of the table:

```
|favorite item|answer|name|
-----------------------------
|color|red|jake|
|animal|bear|jake|
|food|pizza|jake|
|color|blue|sally|
|movie|frozen|sally|
|food|pasta|sally|
```

I have tried using joins and unions, but none of them can get exactly what I'm looking for.

This is the closest I've been able to get:

```
select j.favorite, s.favoite, j.answer,  s.answer  
from testTable j
full join testTable s on (j.favorite=s.favorite) and s.name='sally' 
where j.name = 'jake';
```

But it gives me:

```
-----------------------------
|color|color|red|blue|    
|animal|null|bear|null|   
|food|food|pizza|pasta|
```

I would like for it to include null values for both students like:

```
|color|red|blue|
|animal|bear|null|
|food|pizza|pasta|
|movie|null|frozen|
```

Hope this makes sense and any help is really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`FULL JOIN` is tricky -- and you seem to want that.  The key is filtering *before* the `JOIN`:

```
select j.favorite, s.favoite, j.answer,  s.answer  
from (select j.*
      from testTable j
      where j.name = 'jake'
     ) j full join
     (select s.*
      from testTable s
      where s.name = 'sally'
     ) s
     on j.favorite = s.favorite;
```